# Android studio c++ files can't find directory

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I'm using android studio 1.3 and I'm trying to compile box2d c++. I dumped the Box2D folder into jni folder and tried to compile. I'm getting no such file or diectory errors. I can't understand why. Here is a screenshot. As you can see Box2D is marked in red font in the source file indicating that it can't find the Box2D directory. This makes no sense because it is in that directory.

[image]

Comment: Show us your make files.

Comment: I don't know how to make one. I can't find any examples anywhere.

Comment: I would suggest going through some tutorials first. Please see this: https://github.com/mcxiaoke/box2d-ndk/tree/master/jni